# Input data processing using PHP for security

Tags: php

I am writing a code which will process the user text input in a registration form. I have implemented the following function which make sure that the input data is safe:

```
function input_check($Indata, $dbc) {       // input_check($Indata, $dbc)
    $Indata = trim($Indata);                // remove white spaces 
    $Indata = stripslashes($Indata);        // remove back slashes
    $Indata = strip_tags($Indata);          // remove html tags
    $Indata = htmlspecialchars($Indata);    // convert html entities
    $Indata = mysql_real_escape_string($Indata,$dbc);
    return $Indata;
}
```

Is there any other processing that I have to do in order to ensure that the input is safe?

I meant safe from malicious input data

Comment: Yes, there's `base64_encode()`!

Comment: `base64_encode`ing is so good I often call it `base_sexy_4_encoding` to share my love for this wonderful functon `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy to use all possible escaping mechanisms may be safe, but will make your application too complex - imagine what you need to do, to use the data (which seems to be stored in a MySQL database later, right?) to print it in a html form later.

A more wise approach is, to use only the adequate escaping mechanism depending on the use of the data:

- to store data in a MySQL database, use a database escaping mechanism (btw instead of `mysql_real_escape_string()` which is deprecated, use [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) or even better use [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) which already does escaping for you)
- to print stored data in html text use `htmlspecialchars()`, possibly in conjunction with `strip_tags()`
- to print stored data in html attributes use `htmlspecialchars()` together with `urlencode()`

... and so on. Then you will most likely be safe of SQLInjection, XSS attacks and so on.

Comment: While this is a good answer I would suggest using `htmlentities` over `htmlspecialchars`, as it is more complete (but that's probably not a killer).

Comment: no, don't use strip_tags, just htmlspecialchars. and make sure to use the flags ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED

Comment: Thanks every one for your contributions. A special thanks to you  Joachim Schirrmacher for your time to expand your answer which is really helpful